# Get data in row with dropdown list

Tags: google-sheets

I created a dropdown list with a range in Sheet2 in Google Spreadsheets.

The dropdown is filled with a bunch of names.

When I select a particular item I want to update another cell next to it with the data that is on Sheet2 from another column.

For example Sheet2 looks like:

```
id,name,date
1,John,2015-04-29
2,Adam,2015-03-01
```

I select John in my dropdown list and I want to display the "date" column of John in another cell on Sheet1.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `John` is selected in C3 and your `name/date` data is in a range named `NamedRange1` please try:

```
  =vlookup(C3,NamedRange1,2,0)
```

If you wanted `ID` VLOOKUP would not be suitable as it does not "look to the left" and the conventional solution would be an INDEX/MATCH combination instead.

Comment: Thanks I managed to get the date using: vlookup(B5,Data!$B$1:$C,2,false) ... but how do you get the ID?